# calculate current nodal voltage method problem

Tags: current

I don't know how he calculated the current and get this result. 
any help please??

[image]

my try

[image]

Comment: Why are there two currents tagged I3?

Comment: I don't know why there are I3
I added my try with which I understand

Comment: @jippie, it's confusing to say the least to mark different currents with the same label but I don't think it's a typo - there are two of I2 and I1 also.  It's odd but it's pretty clear what is meant.

Comment: V1 is a node with three branches, why are there only two terms in your equation for V1?

Comment: The given answer has a typo. The current through R2 (not R1) is 5A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your KCL equations are incomplete.  For node 1, there are 3 currents involved and for node 2, there are 4 currents involved.

Using the first schematic, KCL at node 1 is:

$$I_1 + I_2 = 25A $$

KCL at node 2 is:

$$I_1 + I_3 + I_4 = 20A $$

Be careful to note that \$I_1\$ in the first equation is *not* the same as the \$I_1\$ in the second equation.

In the first equation,

$$I_1 = \frac{V_1}{4\Omega} $$

while in the second equation,

$$I_1 = \frac{V_2 - V_1}{10 \Omega} $$

Comment: if I1 for first eq is not the same as I1 in the second one,how can I solve the two equations

Comment: @user37462, to solve the equations for the node voltages, *you replace each current label with the appropriate Ohm's Law expression*.  Did I not provide you with the appropriate expressions for the two \$I_1\$ labels above?

Comment: ok, I understood it but I have one question
why we include I1 in second node????
I think it 20=I3+I4 only
can you clarify this point please?

Comment: @user37462, two nodes connected by a wire is equivalent to one node.  That is, you can redraw the circuit, shrinking the length of the wire between the 20A source and R3 to zero.  This does not change the circuit and it is then easy to see that this is a *single* node with node voltage V2 and with four currents to consider.  See:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_%28circuits%29   *"For two nodes to be different, their voltages must be different"*